# Aluminum fork dropout potentially compromised - advice?

Tags: repair, fork, damage

I hope y’all can give me some advice. I bought a bike, had it shipped, looks great except one thing — the fork was slightly damaged in shipping. It’s carbon but the aluminum part that attaches to the quick release is narrower on the right side. See pictures comparisons of the 2 below.

The leading edge of the Drive-side fork dropout is squashed back, the axle won't fit through the gap.

Bianchi Via Nirone 7 sora.

Bent dropout:
[image: bent]

The other dropout which is fine:
[image: fine]

The seller insisted on it being steel. The bike shop said carbon but the bottom is aluminum. Any advice would be helpful - is this severely unsafe? With how and where it’s damaged - is the fork totaled?

Comment: The first photo is the bent. The second is not bent.

Comment: You can tell aluminum from steel by using a magnet. This way you'll determine who's right on the material of the fork slots.

Comment: I've embedded your pictures into the question. Welcome to the website, by the way! It would help answering your question if you were more specific about what sort of advice you need.

Comment: Howdy! It appears to be Alu carbon as described on the Bianchi website. 

I guess I’m worried or not worried. Is the slight damage to the base of the fork substantial? Should I replace?

Comment: It‘s Not clear, which direction is bended? One part of the “ring” in direction parallel to the axis? Or perpendicular to it?

Comment: Ultimately this is between the shipping company and the seller and their insurers to figure out who pays for the damage.  Keep pushing the seller, ask for escalation to someone above first level helpdesk, and stay polite.  Just don't take No for an answer.  "I bought a thing, it arrived stuffed, please fix it."    Do keep an accurate record of who you communicated with, dates, times, their name, and what was said/promised.

Comment: Also, please refrain from riding this, or attempting to fix it yourself.

Comment: Howdy. Wow thanks! So I bought it from a coworker. I bought the label too so I was the shipper I suppose. How does that wrinkle this?

Answer (score 6):

Fork is toast, dropout cannot be trusted or reasonably repaired. Carbon forks with steel dropouts basically don't exist. Probably best for everyone is get comped for a fork plus install labor. Shouldn't be a difficult fork to get a suitable replacement for.

Comment: The bike wasn't correctly shipped. A fork needs protection with a specific spacer that would also protect it from side-ways impacts.

Comment: Aye. Where would you recommend looking for a fork?

Comment: If it's at a shop, they'll have suppliers that sell replacement carbon forks with different geometry, brake, and steerer type options. I highly recommend going that route.

Comment: @Carel This can happen with a fork block installed. I've seen it. But it's likely that the box got smashed in the corner where the dropouts were during shipping.